# With WPF validation, how do I trigger other interconnected ui elements to re-check their validation status

Tags: wpf, validation

I've got a wpf form where validation works fine for single-field validation.  I've got the DataAnnotations classes wired up to the IDataErrorInfo class so that they display properly.

Now I've got a more complicated form with more complicated validation.  I've implemented IValidatableObject on the view model, and I see that this is called.  I manually call Validator.TryValidateObject any time a field changes, and I can see that the IDataErrorInfo class properly returns errors.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the UI to recheck it's validation status.  For example, I've got fields A, B, and C that are only required if D is a certain value.  So there's no DataAnnotation flags on those fields -- I just return the list of errors in the Validate implementation of IValidatableObject.

Now when I edit D, no error is displayed in A,B, or C.  If I put something in A, then take it back out, then A will show the error.  But I want all the fields to do it automatically.  Is there a normal way to do this, and in particular, trigger it from the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question a while back and posted it on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7121867/302677)

What I ended up doing was creating an Extension method that hooked into the `PropertyChanging` event and raising the validation error for any properties within the specified `ValidationGroup`

It is used like:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    this.AddValidationGroup(
        new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" },
        GetValidationError, OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

The downside is your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanging` (I was using Entity Framework, and the entities automatically implement that interface)

There is also another answer posted there which doesn't use the `PropertyChanging` event, and may help you.

And of course, there's always the solution of simply raising `OnPropertyChanged("X");` inside the set method of your related properties.

```
public string A
{
    get { return _a; }
    set
    {
        _a = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("A");
        RaisePropertyChanged("B");
        RaisePropertyChanged("C");
        RaisePropertyChanged("D");
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually just did the last -- they weren't EF objects, and it was a lot simpler than I thought